# Problems loading data in a JTable

Tags: java, database, iterator, jtable

I am doing a proyect which is a Database Manager, I have a list at the left side with all the table names I can choose, and in the right side I have the table. The problem is that I am doing something wrong and the JTable shows like this:

[image: My JTable]

Anyone can say me what does that cell values mean?

thanks

Comment: can you post your  model code?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to display hash map values in your table. When it goes to load them, it prints the class name and not the values. Same thing happens if you try to display a JLabel or something like that without using a custom table cell renderer.

Its hard to say for sure though. Please post code and we can help you better.

Comment: Correction: Java prints the value returned by the toString() method. For most classes this is a String containing the class name and the reference ID.

Comment: See, I thought that too, but then I executed this code `System.out.println(new HashMap<Object,Object>());` and it actually print out the empty hashmap. Looks like the Hash Map's toString() is overriden. Thats what lead me to believe something else was going on.

Comment: I assume that the displayed value is truncated - complete is should point to "java.util.HashMap$EntrySet" or one of the other inner classes that have no overidden toString() method.

Comment: @Robert I also agree that the displayed value is trucated. But can you explain why it would point to an inner class that doesnt have an overridden toString() and not the HashMaps toString()?